# How to build a solution that refers to another project without building both solutions i C#

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I'm working with two solutions, **solution_1**(incl. **project_1 and project_2**) and **solution_2**(incl. **project_3**), where I keep getting feature requests from users to add functionality in project_3 in solution_2. The reason why I have to solutions is that another programmer needs to be able to add functionalities into **project_3** and release this, but I don't want him to access the **project_1**.
When I want to release the new feature I have to build and release projects in both solutions, but I've only made changes in **project_3**, so this project should be the only one released.

As for now, **project_1** has an reference to the assembly **project_3**, where the property `Copy to local` is FALSE but this results in this error:

```
Assembly 'project_3.dll' must be strong signed in order to be marked as a prerequisite.
```

Whenever I build project_3 the output path is set to a folder which is visible to both solutions.

My point is that I don't want to keep building and releasing **project_1** in **solution_1** in which I haven't made any changes, but only build and release **project_3** in **solution_2**, which actually has changes in it, for the new features to be available for the users.

Comment: I feel that what you are refering as solutions are not solutions but projects...

Comment: can't you just merge the 2 solutions into 1 solution?

Comment: if you want to have different releases you don't need to have 2 solutions. just make branch the work you have.

Comment: @daryal you're right! I'll edit the question. Too early for me in the morning to ask questions I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

A project can be in multiple solutions.  You could simply add **project_3** to **solution_1**, so that when the project changes, you need only recompile the one solution.

Note that if you do this, you should be aware of some issues; mostly common sense stuff, but still:

- Refactoring tools in other solutions don't know about this solution.  They might break dependencies, in other words (e.g. if solution_2 is refactored, solution_1's dependency on project_3, which is in both, is problematic).
- Preferably don't open both solutions simultaneously to avoid overwriting your own changes.
- Though VS.NET supports this fine, it doesn't make any particular effort to make it simple.  So if your project files contain references to solution-wide variables, you need to manually ensure that's fine (if you've any custom build steps, for instance)
- In particular, nuget stores its packages by default in a solution-level /packages folder.  If a project is in different solutions, this package folder might be in a different location (a different relative path), which will be stored in the project file and cause problems.  I'd avoid different (relative) paths to the nuget folders.

You should not be referencing the *assembly* project_3 creates, you should include the existing project 3 in solution 1, and reference the project *itself*.  (This has nothing to do with strong signing - that's a different error).

Comment: I see your point and it makes sense, but for some reason I can't explain myself. What I want is **project_1** in **solution_1** to refer to **project_3** from **solution_2**, so whenever I build and release a setup project for **project_3**, **project_1** sees the changes in the assembly **project_3** without me doing anything about any project in **solution_1**. Does this makes more sense to you? I'm sorry for my way of explaining this. I find it hard...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a source of misunderstanding, but to be explicit:  There's no such thing as project_3 "from" solution_2 - there's a project, and it happens to be listed in a solution.  You can list it in another solution just fine.  Projects aren't "owned" by solutions in some way.  As to the setup project - this is orthogonal.  If solution 2 also lists project 3, then it will see any changes that have been made without requiring further actions.  But you'll still need to build solution 2 for those changes to actually affect build outputs.

Comment: Iøm new at this, so there might be a misunderstanding. I'll just have to think a little more about this. I've been reading some different articles/fora and I think i need to take a whole other approach to find a solution for this problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: But you do understand that you can have project_3 in *both* solutions?  That's the important bit.

Comment: Yes I do and i tried to see if I could work something out doing that, but without any luck. Instead I made my own code using the `Assembly Class` and `LoadFrom()` method and now its fixed :)

Comment: That's great - but a plain project reference still sounds better as you'll get intellisense etc. - if you want I'll try to walk through the steps in the comments here, maybe we can figure out which it's not working for you.